# the Laurent series of $f(z)=\cos \frac {z}{z+1}$ on $0<|z-1|<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I want to find the Laurent series of $f(z)=\cos \frac {z}{z+1}$ on $0<|z-1|<\infty$, and I don't understand, if it is ok, that a point $-1$ is in $0<|z-1|<\infty$, also I don't understand how to find  the Laurent series. I'm looking for any hints. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot have a Laurent series on the annulus $0<|z-1|<\infty$ because $f(z)$ is not holomorphic on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac z{z+1}\right)&=\cos\left(1-\frac1{z+1}\right)\\&=\cos(1)\cos\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)+\sin(1)\sin\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)\\&=\cos(1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!(z+1)^{2n}}+\sin(1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(z+1)^{2n+1}}\\&=\cos(1)+\frac{\sin(1)}{z+1}-\frac{\cos(1)}{2(z+1)^2}-\frac{\sin(1)}{6(z+1)^2}+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: Could you please explain what to do with $cos \frac {1}{z+1}$ in more detail?

Comment: Done. Was it detailed enough?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still don't understand why it is legal to put $(z+1)^{-1}$ into the Taylor series of $cos x$ and $sin x$ at $0$ and say that it is the Laurent?

Comment: I don't understand you comment. Since$$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots,$$we have$$\cos\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)=1-\frac1{2!(z+1)^2}+\frac1{4!(z+1)^4}+\cdots$$and the same thing applies to $\sin\left(\frac1{z+1}\right)$. And have I or have I not obtained a Laurent series whose sum is $\cos\left(\frac z{z+1}\right)$? What more do you need?